# How to Play two Different sound on two different buttons on OnTouchListner Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, touchscreen

I am making an android app. I have added two buttons and assigned two different sounds to them. Now the Button1 shoudl play sound.mp3 and Button2 should play asound.mp3 while press down and sound should be stop on press up. The problem is that both buttons are playing only one sound.

```
package com.example.sound1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private MediaPlayer mp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
}

break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
mp.pause();
}
break;
}
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: it seems you are just overriding the value of the mp, no matter what. the assignment is not done in an actionListener. You should instantiate it inside the ACTION.DOWN event (after, of course figuring out which button triggered it)

Comment: did you manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You must create two media player
2. You must specifiy what button is tuching

Use this code

```
private MediaPlayer mp1;
private MediaPlayer mp2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
             mp1.setLooping(true);
             mp1.start();
        }else{
             mp2.setLooping(true);
             mp2.start();
        }

    }

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
             mp1.pause();
        }else{
             mp2.pause();
        }

    }
    break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For 3 or more Buttons use this

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
private int[] sounds = {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3};
private int[] btns = {R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //others codes
    for (int btn : btns) {
        (ImageButton) this.findViewById(btn).setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            for (int i = 0 ; i<btns.length ; i++){
                if (v.getId() == btns[i]){
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            mp.start();
        }

        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            for (int btn : btns) {
                if (v.getId() == btn) {
                    mp.pause();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: two mediaPlayers are an option. and while there are only two buttons, it doesn't make for much overhead or redundant code. Try the same with 25 buttons. will you add 25 mediaPlayers, and if-else's for all of them?
It's easier to have in the ACTION_DOWN: if (event.getId() == [button1]) {
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(... // params for sound 1 );
.... After all, the setLooping and start should not be duplicated

Comment: @AwaisAhmed happy coding, please accept answer if it works

Comment: Just 1 thing. What if i want to create three buttons with three different sound? Kindly revised the code with three please. i will be glad

Comment: @AwaisAhmed did you check ?

Comment: Thanks Radesh. I have made a minor modification in your revised code by putting mp.setlooping (true); right after mp.start();.. But now another problem I have three buttons 1, 2 and 3 with sounds A, B and C. when i press 1 button A sound start. After releasing  1 Button when I press 2 Button B sound starts. But When i press 2 Button without releasing 1 Button (Multi button touch) then the Button 1 (Sound A) loops does not stop even after button release and play even in background. I have to close my app to stop the loop.

Comment: @AwaisAhmed I can not solve all your problems, there are a lot of bugs that you must one by one solve, you are programmer and your work is solve bugs not write only code

Answer (score 0):

Create two instance of MediaPlayer instance

For the first sound

```
MediaPlayer mpFirst = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
```

For the second sound

```
MediaPlayer mpSecond = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound);
```

use these two instances appropriately

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound); // this is your problem. you set the MediaPlayer fixed to this sound
}
```

You should set the sound based on which Button was clicked.
I haven't used android before, so I'm not 100% sure of the code, but you'll need something like this:

```
package com.example.sound1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private MediaPlayer mp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
// remove this -> mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
// remove this -> mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
if ( event.getActionSource() == R.id.button1) {
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
} else if ( event.getActionSource() == R.id.button2 ) {
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.asound);
} else { mp = null; }
if ( mp != null ) {
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
}
}

break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
if (mp != null ) mp.pause();
}
break;
}
return true;
}
}
```